# Linked Service is automatically unselected after closing the Azure Data Flow tab

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

I think I might have found a bug on Azure Data Flow. The error triggers after selecting the following options in a Azure SQL Database sink:

[image]

If I close the Data Flow tab the following validation errors appears:

[image]

If I open the Data Flow again to check what happened I find that the Linked Service was unselected automatically:

[image]

I compared the Data Flow scripts to see if something is being erased, but they are identical. It seems as if the Linked Service is saved in memory and when you close the Data Flow tab you lose that configuration...

[image]

Is this a known issue? Can I fix it somehow?

**EDIT:**

I compared the "code" and I confirmed that the linked service is being deleted when I close the Data Flow tab:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried closing the ADF editor and your browser and then starting again?  Weird things like this can happen sometimes, and it never hurts to have a fresh instance.

Comment: I turned off my ad-blocker, deleted all my navigation data (e.g. cookies), closed the browser, reopened the browser and loged in again, but the problem stills occurs. I am using the latest version of Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed your step and my Linked Service was still Selected. So you can try to close your browser and start again. Sometimes these things would happen as JeffRamos says.

Comment: I turned off my ad-blocker, deleted all my navigation data (e.g. cookies), closed the browser, reopened the browser and loged in again, but the problem stills occurs. I am using the latest version of Google Chrome.

Comment: PG team is fixing this and the fix is rolling out by region. It should be in all regions by end of this week.

Comment: @FangLiu you are right. They fixed this bug. It is working properly now.